# Compiling only in release mode

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, managed-c++

our software solution contains a Managed C++ library project which can be only compiled if the PC the compilation is running on has a valid installation of VS2008.
Usually I am the only developer working on this project, however my colleagues should be able to compile the solution as a whole with a precompiled version of this library, which is version controlled together with other third-party library dependencies.

So we've decided to add a reference on the DLL into the project which depends on the library, not adding the project itself as a reference. Now my question: **is it possible to use the precompiled version when using a specific configuration (i.e. Debug) and to compile the library from scratch when building the project in Release mode, e.g. on a Jenkins server?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's kinda of the point of using a build automation tool like Jenkins.  You get to choose what is built and when.  You just need to make sure that the built assembly is pushed to everybody's machine.  Perhaps by making it available on a well-known share on the build server so the assembly reference can always be found.

Comment: But I've got no idea how to apply these settings to VS2010 ... is it possible to define a target-based library dependency (debug - use precompiled dependency, release - use project dependency)?

Comment: No, the solution file does not support the Conditional msbuild command, it can only appear in project files.  You simply need two solutions, one that just creates this assembly and is only ever built on the server or your machine.  Another that the devs use.